# Any way to override the and operator in Python?

Tags: python

I tried overriding `__and__`, but that is for the & operator, not *and* - the one that I want. Can I override *and*?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You cannot override the `and`, `or`, and `not` boolean operators.

Comment: Noteably, [PEP335](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) made a proposal and was eventually rejected.

Answer (score 49):

No you can't override `and` and `or`. With the behavior that these have in Python (i.e. short-circuiting) they are more like control flow tools than operators and overriding them would be more like overriding `if` than + or -.

You *can* influence the truth value of your objects (i.e. whether they evaluate as true or false) by overriding `__nonzero__` (or `__bool__` in Python 3).

Comment: The control flow (lazy evaluation of the right hand side) semantics could still be maintained by having the overload be a binary operator where right hand side is passed as a callable instead of as a value.

Comment: @DRayX Not even that is necessary. The short-circuit part could simply be preserved as part of the operator, and the hypothetical `__and2__` function would only be called, if the first argument evaluates to a truthy value. `a and b` would be equivalent to `a.__and2__(b) if a else a` then. Not as regular as other operator functions, but that choice would enforce retaining short circuiting and provide better performance.

Answer (score 3):

Not really.  There's no special method name for the short-circuit logic operators.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't overload `__and__` you can use [infix](http://tomerfiliba.com/blog/Infix-Operators/) to overload and. You would use &and& to represent the and operator in this case.

Comment: No, you can not. (Since `and` is a keyword in Python.)