# Why does pandas use (&, |) instead of the normal, pythonic (and, or)?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) explain that this is the convention, but I was wondering why?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=list('abcdef'), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df[(df.A < .5) | (df.B > .5)])
print(df[(df.A < .5) or (df.B > .5)])
```

Returns the following:

```
          A         B         C         D
a -0.284669 -0.277413  2.524311 -1.386008
b -0.190307  0.325620 -0.367727  0.347600
c -0.763290 -0.108921 -0.467167  1.387327
d -0.241815 -0.869941 -0.756848 -0.335477
e -1.583691 -0.236361 -1.007421  0.298171
f -3.173293  0.521770 -0.326190  1.604712
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(df[(df.A < .5) or (df.B > .5)])   
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because `&` and `|` are overridable (customizable). You can write the code that drives the operators for any `class`.

The logic operators `and` and `or`, on the other hand, have standard behavior that cannot be modified.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for the relevant documentation.

Comment: I guess related question/answer for the second part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471546/any-way-to-override-the-and-operator-in-python

Comment: because each result is a a list of true/false, which correlates closely to bits, and so a bitwise operator absolutely makes sense (in addition to the answer given here... plus how did you make your name do that(@answerer)?)

Comment: It's just some unicode and some normal characters n -> u, m -> w, d -> p

Comment: Back in the BBS days, we used to write that as `umop apsidn`, just using good ol' ASCII. Close enough...

Comment: Also: the *reason* that `and` and `or` aren't overrideable is because they short-circuit. That is, the second argument might not even be evaluated.