# operator overload python custom class

Tags: class, python-2.7, operator-overloading

say I want to overload an operator (lets say `+` for now) for some class I've created,

```
class A (object):
    #code here
```

and then:

```
a = A()
b = A()
```

what would I do to define:

```
c = a + b
```

or something along those lines?
(note: this question is purely theoretical I will likely use this at some time, just not currently (unless its really easy and I really need a use for it))

(p.s. if it is possible to do this for other things such as `and`, `or`, `not`, `str`, e.t.c.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `A` is the first operand of the binary operator, you should define [`A.__add__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__). If `A` was the second operand and there was no way to change the class of the first operand, you would have to define [`A.__radd__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__).

[Full reference for magic methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: thank you, is their a way to do this for `and` or `or` or `not`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471546/any-way-to-override-the-and-operator-in-python

Comment: lets say I would like to `def __pow__(self, y)` outside of a class. Better yet redefine it for say the list type. How would I do that? is it even possible?

Comment: Defining methods outside a class and monkeypatching them after is possible. Doing it with a magic method is questionable. But monkeypatching a type defined in C is impossible.

Comment: oh! I didn't know lists were predefined in C!