# SQLAlchemy: unexpected results when using `and` and `or`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, boolean

I have a declarative base class `News`:

```
class News(Base):
    __tablename__ = "news"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = Column(String)
    author = Column(String)
    url = Column(String)
    comments = Column(Integer)
    points = Column(Integer)
    label = Column(String)
```

I also have a function `f(title)`, that gets a string and returns one of 3 variants of strings: 'good', 'maybe' or 'never'. 
I try to get filtered rows:

```
rows = s.query(News).filter(News.label == None and f(News.title) == 'good').all()
```

But the program fails, raising this error:

```
raise TypeError("Boolean value of this clause is not defined")
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: @IljaEverilä You should post that as an answer, I almost missed your comment and was already writing the same thing.

Comment: I was trying to find an existing duplicate for this, but to some surprise could not.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
News.label == None and f(News.title) == 'good'
#                  ^^^ here
```

Python does not allow overriding the behaviour of boolean **operations** `and` and `or`. You can influence them to some extent with [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) in Python 3 and [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) in Python 2, but all that does is that it [defines the truth value of your object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471546/any-way-to-override-the-and-operator-in-python).

If the objects in question had not implemented `__bool__` and thrown the error, or the implementation had not thrown, you would've gotten possibly rather cryptic errors due to the [short-circuiting nature of `and` and `or`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

```
In [19]: (News.label == 'asdf') and True
Out[19]: <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7f62c416fa58>

In [24]: (News.label == 'asdf') or True
Out[24]: True
```

because

```
In [26]: bool(News.label == 'asdf')
Out[26]: False
```

This could and would lead to hair pulling in the form of incorrect SQL expressions:

```
In [28]: print(News.label == 'asdf' or News.author == 'NOT WHAT YOU EXPECTED')
news.author = :author_1
```

To produce boolean SQL expressions either use the [`and_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_), [`or_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_), and [`not_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_) sql expression functions, or the binary [`&`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators.__and__), [`|`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.__or__), and [`~`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators.__invert__) operator overloads:

```
# Parentheses required due to operator precedence
filter((News.label == None) & (f(News.title) == 'good'))
```

or

```
filter(and_(News.label == None, f(News.title) == 'good'))
```

or pass multiple criterion to a call to [`Query.filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter):

```
filter(News.label == None, f(News.title) == 'good')
```

or combine multiple calls to `filter()`:

```
filter(News.label == None).filter(f(News.title) == 'good')
```

Comment: Very thorough, thanks . Are Any idea if one of these methods is preferrable or better performant?  I kind of like just calling .filter() twice as it's very readbile and can put each statement on a newline

Comment: I'd imagine there being negligible difference in performance, since calls to `filter()` simply append new criterion to the `Query` – it is compiled to SQL and emitted only when you call `all()` etc. So choose the method that suits you best.