# how left outer join in sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, outer-join

I want implement left outer join in sqlalchemy. the sql query is like this:

```
select * from skills left join user__skill on user__skill.skill_id=skills.id and  user__skill.user_id=4
```

and what i wrote in sqlalchemy is :

```
skills = db.session.query(Skill, User_Skill.skill_id).\
            outerjoin(User_Skill, User_Skill.skill_id==Skill.id and User_Skill.user_id==4).\
            order_by(Skill.name).all()
```

but it doesn't filter for a user and show all users skills.

how can i write this code?

Comment: Have you tried comparing your sql with sql generated by sqlalchemy?

Comment: how i must  create it?

Comment: http://nicolascadou.com/blog/2014/01/printing-actual-sqlalchemy-queries/
You can just print your query (without `.all()`) or use specific sql dialect to see sql sent to the database.

Comment: yes. It is like this: 
`SELECT skills.id AS skills_id, skills.name_en AS skills_name_en, skills.name_fa AS skills_name_fa, user__skill.skill_id AS user__skill_skill_id
FROM skills LEFT OUTER JOIN user__skill ON user__skill.skill_id = skills.id ORDER BY skills.name`  
there is not `user__skill.user_id=4` condition in the generated query.

Comment: For background on why using the `and` **operation** does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681231/sqlalchemy-unexpected-results-when-using-and-and-or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Use `and_` from `sqlalchemy` to join `join` conditions

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

skills = db.session.query(Skill, User_Skill.skill_id).\
            outerjoin(User_Skill, and_(User_Skill.skill_id==Skill.id, 
                                       User_Skill.user_id==4)).\
            order_by(Skill.name).all()
```

---

Old, wrong answer (different results):

Use `.filter` to limit your results. Change your query to:

```
skills = db.session.query(Skill, User_Skill.skill_id).\
            outerjoin(User_Skill, User_Skill.skill_id==Skill.id).\
            filter(User_Skill.user_id==4).\
            order_by(Skill.name).all()
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the 2 queries presented in the answer will have different results.