# SqlAlchemy Case with multiple conditions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to do something like this:

```
x = db_session.query(
    Candidate,
    func.count(case([(Jobs.interview_type == 'PHONE_SCREEN' and Jobs.interview_type == 'INCLINED' , 1)])),
    func.count(case([(Jobs.interview_type == 'PHONE_SCREEN' and Jobs.interview_type == 'NOT_INCLINED', 1)])),
    func.count(case([(Jobs.interview_type == 'IN_HOUSE', 1)])),
    func.count(case([(Jobs.interview_type == 'EVALUATION', 1)]))
    ).\
    join(Jobs, Jobs.candidate_id == Candidate.candidate_id).\
    filter(Candidate.candidate_id == '6236738').\
    first()
```

However its not picking up the second condition in `case`. Is this possible?

I got it working with `and_` but its not giving the right answer

```
func.count(case([(and_(Jobs.interview_type == 'PHONE_SCREEN', Jobs.interview_type == 'INCLINED'), 1)])),
```

should return 2, but its returning 0

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681231/sqlalchemy-unexpected-results-when-using-and-and-or

Comment: What database are you using? Also, your logic is off; how could `interview_type` be PHONE_SCREEN and INCLINED at the same time? I'm guessing you meant to compare some other column against INCLINED.

Comment: OH! that should be interview_result ... thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `sqlalchemy.and_` instead of the `and` operator:

```
and_(Jobs.interview_type == 'PHONE_SCREEN',
     Jobs.interview_type == 'INCLINED')
```

Comment: Thats right! I'm stuck trying to put everything together...my syntax is off. Can you include `func.count(case[(...)])` with that too?

Comment: I got it working, but its not returning the desired result. I put updated solution. can you take a look?

Comment: One thing to try is `distinct(func.count(case()))`, but I'd want to look at the SQL that sqlalchemy generates to debug it further.

Comment: @StephenFuhry Hi, how to use `and_` with more than 2 values ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496386/sqlalchemy-case-with-multiple-conditions-and-more-than-two-values