# Filtering by a boolean hybrid_property in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using a hybrid_property to generate a calculated property that indicates if an article is published based on its scheduled publish date and whether or not it "is_published":

```
class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    publish_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
    is_published = db.Column(db.Boolean,index=True,default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article {}>'.format(self.id)

    @hybrid_property
    def published(self):
        """Returns true if the publish date is at or before the current time and is_published is true."""
        return self.is_published and self.publish_date <= datetime.now()
```

Given the following set of articles:

Article 1:
Publish date: 2020-5-12
is_published: True

Article 2:
Publish date: 2020-5-13
is_published: False

I can perform the following check:

```
>>> Article.query.all()[0].published
True
>>> Article.query.all()[1].published
False
```

But when querying, the filter returns as if the value were true for this calculated field for all articles:

```
>>> Article.query.filter_by(published=False).all()
[]
>>> Article.query.filter_by(published=True).all()
[<Article 1>, <Article 2>]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to quickly and easily filter by this basic calculation?

Comment: You're running into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681231/sqlalchemy-unexpected-results-when-using-and-and-or

Comment: @IljaEverilä, I'm not sure I follow... I'm not getting an error when filtering, only incorrect results, and the property appears to be returning the correct boolean value? Could you explain with more detail how this is relevant?

Comment: When `self.is_published and self.publish_date <= datetime.now()` is evaluated in query context the resulting query is not what you'd expect, even if no error was raised. It will be either `self.is_published` or `self.publish_date <= datetime.now()` expression, due to the short circuiting nature of `and` in Python. Looks like you're getting the latter.

Comment: Oh, I see! Okay, so I see how I can resolve this in the query, I could just very easily do .filter(Article.publish_date <= datetime.utcnow() | Article.is_published==False), which is working for me, but is there any way to push this logic into the hybrid property to reduce the complexity of filtering?

Comment: There is: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior, define the expression to use in query context explicitly.