# Python overload object.__and__ method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a class and want to overload the __and__ function

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, name, pages):
        self.name = name
        self.pages = pages

    def __and__(self, other):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.name, other.name)
```

When I run this

```
Book('hamlet', 50) and Book('macbeth', 60)
```

I would expect to get 'hamlet, macbeth'

However, it appears the overload does nothing.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The `__and__` method is an override for the and operator `&`:

```
>>> Book('hamlet', 50) & Book('macbeth', 60)
'hamlet, macbeth'
```

Sadly, you [can not override the `and` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/471546/182402).

Comment: But you could override `__bool__ / __nonzero__`

Comment: @timgeb That wouldn't help do what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @khelwood of course not, I just mentioned this for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

The `__and__` method is actually grouped with the [numeric type methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), therefore it does not represent *logical* and (which is the `and` keyword) but rather the `&` operator

```
>>> Book('hamlet', 50) & Book('macbeth', 60)
'hamlet, macbeth'
```