# Isn't the keyword "and" an operator in python? Why?

Tags: python, syntax, grammar, operator-keyword, keyword

I couldn't find the official glossary of python operators but at least it seems that [operator library of python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) doesn't include `and` or `or` keyword. They do have `operator.and_`, but it's for bitwise and operator(`&`). What makes me more confused is that they do include `is` or `not` keywords as operators.

In short, isn't `and`(and `or`) an operator? If it isn't, what is the standard of being an operator in Python? I though I'm pretty familiar with python but this problem confuses me a lot at the moment.

Comment: `and` and `or` are operators, but they are not overridable in the way that some other operators are.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471546/any-way-to-override-the-and-operator-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's an operator. But it's not like the other operators in the `operator` module.

`and` short-circuits (i.e., it evaluates its second argument only if necessary). `or` is similar. Therefore, neither can be written as a function, because arguments to functions are always fully evaluated before the function is called. In some cases this would make no real difference, but when the second argument contains a function call with side effects (such as I/O), or a lengthy calculation, `and`'s behavior is very different from that of a function call.

You *could* implement it by passing at least the second argument as a function:

```
def logical_and(a, b):
    if not a:
       return a
    return b()
```

Then you could call it as follows:

```
logical_and(x, lambda: y)
```

But this is a rather unorthodox function call, and doesn't match the way the other operators work, so I'm not surprised the Python developers didn't include it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I see your point. Just to clarify, we can say `and` and `or` are operators in python, right?

Comment: Yes, they definitely are operators.

Comment: @DerekKim In the Python console, call `help()` enter `OPERATORS` and you'll see them listed there, if you are still with doubts.

Comment: @progmatico Wow. Thank you, too.