# Is it okay to use python operators for tensorflow tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, infix-operator, prefix-operator, xla

**TL;DR**
Is `(a and b)` equivalent to `tf.logical_and(a, b)` in terms of optimization and performance? (`a` and `b` are tensorflow tensors)

**Details**:
I use python with tensorflow. My first priority is to make the code run fast and my second priority is to make it readable. I have working and fast code that, for my personal feeling, looks ugly:

```
@tf.function
# @tf.function(jit_compile=True)
def my_tf_func():
    # ...

    a = ... # some tensorflow tensor
    b = ... # another tensorflow tensor

    # currently ugly: prefix notation with tf.logical_and
    c = tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.logical_and(a, b))

    # more readable alternative: infix notation:
    c = tf.math.count_nonzero(a and b)

    # ...
```

The code that uses [prefix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) works and runs fast, but I don't think it's very readable due to the prefix notation (it's called prefix notation, because the name of the operation `logical_and` comes before the operands `a` and `b`).

Can I use [infix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation), i.e. the alternative at the end of above code, with usual python operators like `and`, `+`, `-`, or `==` and still get all the benefits of tensorflow on the GPU and compile it with XLA support? Will it compile to the same result?

The same question applies to unary operators like `not` vs. `tf.logical_not(...)`.

<sub>This question was crossposted at https://software.codidact.com/posts/289588 .</sub>

Comment: `and` and `tf.logical_and` do different things, first of all. `tf.logical_and(a, b)` is element-wise logical AND if `a` and `b` are both tensors, while `a and b` is `a` unless `a` is empty and `b` otherwise (because `and` is controlled only by `__bool__`, you can't overload `and` operator for custom classes, and `tf.Tensor` is truthy iff its shape is not tuple of zeros, AFAIC). For `+` this should not give a performance penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, **no**.

It depends on the specific operator. As you may know, [Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) allows to override the behavior of operators by re-defining special methods of a class. Tensorflow re-defines and most (if not all) of them for its `Tensor` class, and thankfully also documents their behavior, so you can easily check [the documentation for `tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor).

Some operators might behave as you intend them to. For example, `tensor_a + tensor_b` is the same as `tensor_a.__add__(tensor_b)` or `tf.math.add(tensor_a, tensor_b)`.

Some of them might not. For example, `if not some_tensor: ...` will raise an exception because the `__bool__` method of `tf.Tensor` is specifically designed to avoid misuse and raise an exception every time a tensor is used as a boolean. On the other hand, `x = not t` will be `tf.logical_not(t)` *if `t` is a boolean tensor* (its `dtype` is bool), but will perform a bitwise negation for non-boolean tensors ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.13.0/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L1940)). Therefore, you will have to be careful when you use operators instead of explicit methods.

In your example `tf.logical_and(a, b)` can be written as `a & b` according to [the documentation for `tf.logical_and()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/logical_and). The expression `a and b` will raise an exception for the same reason as above, since in Python you cannot override the logical `and` and `or` operators (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/471546/3889449)), and `__bool__` will be called.